# FileWriter and PrintWriter won't output to file

Tags: java, flush, filewriter, printwriter, println

I have this code

```
public User createnewproflie() throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("users.txt",true); //creates new obj that permits to append text to existing file
    PrintWriter userfile = new PrintWriter(fwriter); //creates new obj that prints appending to file as the arg of the obj is a pointer(?) to the obj that permits to append
    String filename= "users.txt";
    Scanner userFile = new Scanner(filename); //creates new obj that reads from file
    User usr=new User(); //creates new user istance
    String usrname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter user name: "); //acquires usrname

    userfile.println("USER: "+usrname+"\nHIGHSCORE: 0\nLASTPLAY: 0");     //writes usrname in file
    userfile.flush();
    usr.setName(usrname); //gives usr the selected usname

    return usr;
}
```

and it doesn't output on the file... can someone help please?
i knew that flush would output all of the buffered text but it doesn't seem to work for some strange reason...

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: I was able to run your code and get the file saving correctly. In my file I get the output 
USER: adsfdsf
HIGHSCORE: 0
LASTPLAY: 0
Try giving a fullpath for users.txt like "C:/Temp/users.txt" so you know exactly where the output file gets generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `String` with a `FileWriter` but a [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) *produces values scanned from the specified string* (not from a `File`). Pass a `File` to the `Scanner` constructor (and it's a good idea to pass the same `File` to your `FileWriter`). And you need to `close()` it before you can read it; maybe with a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
File f = new File("users.txt");
try (FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(f,true);
    PrintWriter userfile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);) {
    // ... Write stuff to userfile
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Scanner userFile = new Scanner(f);
```

Finally, I usually prefer something like `File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "users.txt");` so that the file is saved in the user home directory.

Comment: Good point on the Scanner, but the OP isn't actually using the Scanner in his example code (note `userFile` versus `userfile`), which leads me to believe that something else is causing the issue.